# Can 1/4" bead board be used horizontally without sagging?

Tags: ceiling, plywood, porch

I'm looking at using 1/4" bead board plywood on the ceiling of my front porch. However, I'm concerned that it will sag too much if it's attached to 16" OC rafters.

I've got a good stock of 1-by material. If I use that as strapping on 12" centers, would that be sufficient to keep it from sagging?

Comment: I have seen wood paneling used on porches that may have been ok for a while when it was installed but I was usually removing it as part of a remodel, it did sag where there was insulation that had fallen on it and it could have been from a leak or just the moisture in Oregon not sure but it was very dated possibly 60’s and we did a group of homes that were all the same so it did last real wood paneling (this was in the 90’s).

Comment: This won't have any insulation above it, as it's a simple porch roof, @EdBeal, so I'm not worried about that. If I understand, the paneling you removed was installed in the 60s and you removed it roughly 30 years later in the 90s? I'd say a 30-year life span is not unreasonable.

Comment: Yes it was wood veneer I would be concerned if it is a particle board style or even OSB style being that thin it may sag, I mention this because a few years back we installed bead board for wainscoting and a pipe broke in the wall while the power was off and that stuff puffed up worse than particle board we did not expect it to be getting wet when we installed it. Just a caution.

Comment: This is actual plywood with the beading pressed into the surface. I guess the answer is "I'm going to put up strapping 12" OC, and I'll be back in 5-30 years to let you know how long it lasted".

Comment: An adhesive would also help to mitigate sagging if there's something (drywall) present to stick the paneling to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say a quality product can be hung on 16” centers as I mentioned in the comments. Would 12” be better probably. Definitely less chance of sag but a quality veneer product should be fine hung 16 OC.

Comment: I agree. If this was solid pine boards I'd say no, but plywood should have the integrity to span 16" centers.

Comment: I ended up using up my entire stock of 1x material (and about a dozen packs of shims) creating a nice, almost completely flat surface with the 1x at 12" OC. I've nailed it up, now we'll see how long it lasts. Looks good, hope it stays that way.